# Struggling with alignas syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, icc, alignas

I am trying to use `alignas` for pointers that are class members, and frankly I am not sure where I supposed to put it.

For instance:

```
class A
{
private:
    int n;
    alignas(64) double* ptr;    

public:
    A(const int num) : n(num), ptr(new double[num])
    {}
};
```

which I hoped would ensure the data for ptr was aligned on a 64-byte block.
Using the Intel compiler, it doesn't.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Seems to be [working for me](http://rextester.com/LCVUW98273) (note the inordinately large size of `A`). Or were you hoping that the data `ptr` is pointing **to** would be over-aligned? That would require violation of causality.

Comment: Maybe your compiler doesn't support an alignment of 64?

Comment: Thanks Igor, that is showing the source of my misunderstanding.
The pointer is aligned, not the data to which it points.
I was hoping the data block would come out aligned.

Comment: [Only starting with version 15 does ICC support alignment specifiers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler).

Comment: How can the implementation of `new` possibly know that the pointer it produces would eventually be assigned to a variable declared with `alignas`? That's what I mean by causality violation - you expect the implementation to be able to predict the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `alignas(N)` keyword on a member of a class causes this *member* to be aligned according to the specified alignment, not any entity potentially pointed to. After all, when initializing a pointer with a value there is no control to align the already existing objects.

You might want to have a look at [`std::align()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) which takes

1. A specification for the alignment of the returned pointer.
2. The size of the aligned block.
3. A pointer to allocated memory.
4. The amount of the allocated memory.

It returns a correspondingly aligned pointer unless there is not enough space to satisfy both the alignment and size requirements. If thereis not enought space the function return a null pointer.

Comment: Replacing `ptr = x;` with `ptr = decltype(ptr)(x &~ uintptr_t(64-1));` would guarantee that the ptr is aligned on 64 byte boundaries.  Not in a good way, admittedly.

Comment: @Yakk: I think using `std::align()` is preferable. What the implementation does to appropriately align the ponter is entirly up to the implementation. Since your approach is likely to interfere with the memory _in front_ of the pointer you'd probably want to first offset the pointer a suitable amount.

Comment: I think the real problem with my "solution" is that I went off and modified a pointer willy nilly.  The pointer is aligned, but it doesn't point to anything useful.

Comment: Also note that `alignof` and `std::align` are only guaranteed to work for so-called *fundamental alignment* values, i.e., alignment values `<= alignof(std::max_align_t)`, which often is `16`. In the OP code, one should thus check the respective implementation for support of *extended alignment* values.